# mapPartition on Dataset[Case class] throwing class not found exception

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataset, apache-spark-dataset

I am trying to run map partition on dataset of user case class.
On local box its working fine, but when I run it on yarn cluster I am getting an exception:

```
scala.ScalaReflectionException: Person in JavaMirror with sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@1761e840 of type class sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader in [class path]
```

I am trying to do this operation :

```
case class Person(name: String, age: Long)
val df = sparkSession.read.parquet("path").as[Person]
df.mapPartitions((iter: Iterator[Person]) => {
   //computations
})
```

I am working on Spark 2.0
Can some one help with this ?

Comment: How do you execute the code? Is this part of a Spark application or spark-shell session?

Comment: @JacekLaskowski  
via spark-submit. spark application

Comment: What's the command line to execute spark-submit?